# python - How to add IAM bindings in GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add give a role to an user, on a folder.

I have this kind of working, but it actually replaces all the bindings on the folder:

```
        from google.cloud import resourcemanager_v3
        from google.iam.v1 import iam_policy_pb2  # type: ignore

        def sample_set_iam_policy():

            client = resourcemanager_v3.FoldersClient()

            request = iam_policy_pb2.SetIamPolicyRequest(
                resource="folders/123456",
                policy = {
                "bindings": [
                    {
                    "role": "roles/owner",
                    "members": [
                        "user:email@example.com"
                    ]
                    }
                ]
                }
            )

            response = client.set_iam_policy(request=request)

            print(response)

        sample_set_iam_policy()
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: get the policy first, append the user to the members list and then do a SetIamPolicy. The SetIamPolicy simply overwrites the existing one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to make it work.
Based on this example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/iam/api-client/quickstart.py
, i had to modify it for Folders, instead of Projects

This helped me on how to build the API call
I had to use Resource Manager V3, because V1 cannot do getIamPolicy
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/folders/getIamPolicy

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import google.auth
import googleapiclient.discovery


def quickstart(folder_id, member, _role):
    """Gets a policy, adds a member, prints their permissions, and removes the member."""

    # Role to be granted.
    role = _role

    # Initializes service.
    crm_service = initialize_service()

    # Grants your member the role on the folder.
    modify_policy_add_role(crm_service, folder_id, role, member)

    # Gets the project's policy and prints all members with the role.
    policy = get_policy(crm_service, folder_id)
    binding = next(b for b in policy["bindings"] if b["role"] == role)
    print(f'Role: {(binding["role"])}')
    print("Members: ")
    for m in binding["members"]:
        print(f"[{m}]")

    # Removes the member from the 'Log Writer' role.
    # modify_policy_remove_member(crm_service, folder_id, role, member)


def initialize_service():
    """Initializes a Cloud Resource Manager service."""

    credentials, _ = google.auth.default(
        scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
    )
    crm_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        "cloudresourcemanager", "v3", credentials=credentials
    )
    return crm_service


def modify_policy_add_role(crm_service, folder_id, role, member):
    """Adds a new role binding to a policy."""

    policy = get_policy(crm_service, folder_id)

    binding = None
    for b in policy["bindings"]:
        if b["role"] == role:
            binding = b
            break
    if binding is not None:
        binding["members"].append(member)
    else:
        binding = {"role": role, "members": [member]}
        policy["bindings"].append(binding)

    set_policy(crm_service, folder_id, policy)


def modify_policy_remove_member(crm_service, folder_id, role, member):
    """Removes a  member from a role binding."""

    policy = get_policy(crm_service, folder_id)

    binding = next(b for b in policy["bindings"] if b["role"] == role)
    if "members" in binding and member in binding["members"]:
        binding["members"].remove(member)

    set_policy(crm_service, folder_id, policy)


def get_policy(crm_service, folder_id, version=3):
    """Gets IAM policy for a project."""


    policy = (
        crm_service.folders()
        .getIamPolicy(
            resource=f"folders/{folder_id}",
            body={"options": {"requestedPolicyVersion": version}},
        )
        .execute()
    )
    return policy


def set_policy(crm_service, folder_id, policy):
    """Sets IAM policy for a project."""

    policy = (
        crm_service.folders()
        .setIamPolicy(resource=f"folders/{folder_id}",
                      body={"policy": policy})
        .execute()
    )
    return policy


if __name__ == "__main__":

    role = "roles/browser"
    # TODO: replace with your folder ID
    folder_id = "123456"
    # TODO: Replace with the ID of your member in the form 'user:member@example.com'.
    # or serviceAccount: if you want to assign to a service account
    member = "user:member@example.com"
    quickstart(folder_id, member, role)
```